# How to handle requests containing given snippets (like phpmyadmin) to another domain using NGINX?

Tags: nginx, rewrite, regex

I'd like to redirect all the requests which include any of the words "php" and "admin" (like https://example.com/phpmyadmin) to http://www.cyberpolice.cn

I wrote a rewrite line and placed it inside the server block, but it doesn't work.

```
rewrite (.*php.*)(.*admin.*)|(.*php.*)|(.*admin.*) http://www.cyberpolice.cn permanent;
```

Also tried:

```
rewrite ^(.*php.*)(.*admin.*)|(.*php.*)|(.*admin.*)$ http://www.cyberpolice.cn permanent;
```

Answer (score 0):

At last I found a solution. In the server block:

```
  location ~* (.*php.*)(.*admin.*)|(.*php.*)|(.*admin.*) {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.cyberpolice.cn;
  }
```